# How to lower mouse acceleration if it is allready at lowest setting in gnome3 config

Tags: gnome3, mouse, xinput

I want to lower mouse sensitivity in gnome3 desktop, but when I open appropriate settings panel I see that settings are at already lowest setting:

[image: Screenshot depicting the problem]

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on responses from: http://www.rdoxenham.com/?p=288 and https://superuser.com/questions/259216/disabling-mouse-acceleration-in-x-org-linux you can use `xinput` command.

## Find your device

```
 xinput 

 Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ↳ A4TECH USB Device                         id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ↳ A4TECH USB Device                         id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
 ....
```

You need to find a device that is named like your pointing device (in my case A4TECH USB Device).

## Find properties of your device

You may try to use:

```
xinput list-props "A4TECH USB Device"
```

In my case I had to use numeric id's since (have no idea why) my device was apperaing twice

```
xinput list-props 12
```

## Set properties

I needed to set `"Device Accel Constant Deceleration"`,

```
xinput --set-prop 17 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.7
```

## Make a script

This must be executed on x start, so make script out of it and add it to your gnome session.

Answer (score 2):

From the command line I normally use:

```
xset m 0
```

To get rid of mouse acceleration completely.